# Extending function to holomorphic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Good day, I am having some problems with this question. Our supervisor's notes gave an answer, but she doesn't know how to get to it (it was set by an old lecturer).

> Given a continuous function $f: S(0,1)\to R$, construct a holomorphic function $g:B(0,1) \to C$ which extends to a holomorphic $h:\overline{B(0,1)} \to C$ such that the real part of $h$ is equal to $f$ for all $x \in S(0,1)$.

$S(0,1)$ is circle of radius $1$ about $0$. $B(0,1)$ and $B(0,1)$ are the open and closed balls of radius $1$ about $0$, respectively.

The solution in the notes was $\displaystyle h(z) = \int_0^1 \frac{f(e^{2\pi i \theta})}{1-ze^{-2\pi i \theta}} \, d\theta $. I would like for someone to show how this was obtained, or if it was even correct. Much thanks.

(I tried to see if it has properties the question wants, but I could not simplify or evaluate it with what I know).

Comment: It's not correct. In general, $g$ doesn't extend continuously to $\overline{B(0,1)}$. Only the _real part_ of $g$ extends continuously to the closed disk and has boundary values $f$. Do you know about harmonic functions?

Comment: it comes from the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Answer (score 1):

> (I tried to see if it has properties the question wants, but I could not simplify or evaluate it with what I know).

The only values of $z$ for which you need to evaluate $h(z)$ are those on the boundary.  As for "properties the question wants", there seem to be two of those:

- The function $h$ is holomorphic; and
- The real part of $h$ restricted to the boundary is $f$.

To show $h$ is holomorphic, I'd try using [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem):

\begin{align}
\int\limits_\text{some closed curve} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! h(z)\,dz & = \int\limits_\text{curve} \int_0^1 \frac{f(e^{2\pi i \theta})}{1-ze^{-2\pi i \theta}} \, d\theta \, dz \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^1 \int\limits_\text{curve} \frac{f(e^{2\pi i \theta})}{1-ze^{-2\pi i \theta}} \, dz\,d\theta & & \text{Is this step valid?  See below.} \\[10pt]
& = \int_0^1 0 \,d\theta & & \ldots\,\text{and is this step valid?} \\[10pt]
& = 0.
\end{align}

The interchange of order of integration is valid if the double integral of the absolute value of the function is finite.  That's Fubini's theorem.  And that holds if the function being integrated is bounded and continuous.

For now, I'm leaving this as an incomplete answer, not addressing the second bullet point above.

Comment: $h(z)$ is clearly holomorphic on $|z| < 1$ since it is of the form $\int_a^b g(z,t) dt$ where $g(z,t)$ is holomorphic in $z, |z| < 1$ for every $t \in [a,b]$. and that when $f(e^{2  i \pi t})$ is real,  $Re(h(z)) \to f(e^{2i \pi t})$ as $z \to e^{2i \pi t}$ is the Fourier series convergence theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel )

Comment: Thank you both. I will try to verify the claims myself using the theorems you suggested. I would award you both credit but my score is still too low.

Comment: @user1952009 : How do you know that things of that form are holomorphic unless you prove it by a method similar to what is given in my answer or by some other method that you haven't mentioned? $\qquad$

Comment: because if $g(z,t)$ holomorphic in $z \in U$ for every $t \in [a,b]$ and is supposed to be integrable on $t\in [a,b]$ then $F(z) =\int_a^b g(z,t) dt$ is continuous and complex differentiable on $U$. for this you can use the Cauchy integral formula $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z,t)= \frac{1}{2 i \pi}\int_{|s-z| = \epsilon} \frac{g(s,t)}{(s-z)^2} ds$ which implies that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z,t)$ is integrable on $t \in [a,b]$ (which is obviously the case here), or simply add the assumption that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g(z,t)$ is integrable on $t \in [a,b]$